# Python exract unique record from csv file

Tags: python

I have one csv file from which I want to keep unique record. In this file I have 4th field which has some text and then human or mouse name. like... RHPN1_HUMAN and EPHA5_MOUSE

So for example:  EPHA5 occurs in both human and mouse so I want to delete this record where as RHPN1 occurs in human only so I want to keep this record.

file1.csv

```
meNOG00001  9606    ENSP00000289013         RHPN1_HUMAN

meNOG00005  10090   ENSMUSP00000060646  EPHA5_MOUSE

meNOG00005  9606    ENSP00000273854         EPHA5_HUMAN

meNOG00006  10090   ENSMUSP00000082503  RGPA1_MOUSE

meNOG00006  9606    ENSP00000202677         RGPA2_HUMAN

meNOG00006  9606    ENSP00000302647         RGPA1_HUMAN

meNOG00010  9606    ENSP00000253669         HAUS8_HUMAN

meNOG00011  10090   ENSMUSP00000017629  TOP2B_MOUSE

meNOG00011  10090   ENSMUSP00000068896  TOP2A_MOUSE

meNOG00011  9606    ENSP00000396704         TOP2B_HUMAN

meNOG00011  9606    ENSP00000411532         TOP2A_HUMAN
```

output.csv

```
meNOG00001  9606    ENSP00000289013         RHPN1_HUMAN

meNOG00006  9606    ENSP00000202677         RGPA2_HUMAN

meNOG00010  9606    ENSP00000253669         HAUS8_HUMAN
```

I tried but my code is not working as I want...

```
file1 = open("file1.csv", "rU")
reader1 = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=',')

d =[]
c =[]
for row in reader1:
    d.append(row[3].split('_')[0])
d=list(set(d))

for row1 in d:
    for row2 in reader1:
        if row1 == row2[3].split('_')[0]:
               c.append(row2)

    file1.seek(0)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')
    for k in c:
        writer.writerow(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import collections
data = collections.OrderedDict()            # 2
with open("file1.csv", "rU") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        key = row[3].split('_')[0]
        if key in data:
            del data[key]                   # 1
        else:
            data[key] = row                 

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(data.values())
```

1. If the key is seen more than once, then delete that item from the dict. As long as keys can be seen **at most twice**, this will remove duplicates.
2. Use an OrderDict so the lines will remain in order. If that is not
   important to you, you could use a regular `dict`.

---

If keys can occur more than twice, then you'll need a different way to keep track of which keys have been seen. You could use a set. For example,

```
import csv
import collections
seen = set()
data = collections.OrderedDict()            
with open("file1.csv", "rU") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        key = row[3].split('_')[0]
        if key in seen:
            del data[key]
        else:
            data[key] = row                 
            seen.add(key)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(data.values())
```

Comment: this give  meNOG00001 9606 ENSP0000028901 RHPN1_HUMAN<br/>
meNOG00005 9606 ENSP00000273854 EPHA5_HUMAN<br/>
meNOG00006 9606 ENSP00000302647 RGPA1_HUMAN<br/>
meNOG00006 9606 ENSP00000202677 RGPA2_HUMAN<br/>
meNOG00010 9606 ENSP00000253669 HAUS8_HUMAN<br/>
meNOG00011 9606 ENSP00000396704 TOP2B_HUMAN<br/>
meNOG00011 9606 ENSP00000411532 TOP2A_HUMAN<br/> I need <br/>meNOG00001  9606    ENSP00000289013         RHPN1_HUMAN<br/>
meNOG00006  9606    ENSP00000202677         RGPA2_HUMAN<br/>
meNOG00010  9606    ENSP00000253669         HAUS8_HUMAN<br/>

Answer (score 0):

Not tested in full but you could use something like this:

```
class OD(OrderedDict):
    coll = set()
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.coll:
            try:
                del self[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        else:
            OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
            self.coll.add(key)
```

the reason for this is that I'm not sure if you will have more than 2 matches. For example if you have an odd number of matching codes you can not match against the keys in the dictionary - as any odd number of keys would be considered unique. However the above WILL work. (this might be overkill though)

```
d = OD()

with open("file1.csv", "rU") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        key = row[3].split('_')[0]
        d[key] = row

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')
    for val in d.values():
        writer.writerow(val)
```